# Could not load solution

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am doing my code on windows system and when I transfer my code to mac and open .sln file then two error occures:

1. Cloud not load solution "Directory of project".
2. Load Operation Failed.

And when we open old code then it works fine.May be there is some version mismatch in new code.

Comment: it could be a million things, can you please give more details? what are  you writing your code with? version of VS?

Comment: and in mac? and what are you using to upload/download the package???

Comment: Nuget package for downloading any plugin.

Comment: Visual Studio in Windows: 16.6.4  Visual Studio in Mac: 8.6.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed in directory problem solved!

Comment: I granted permissions to the project folder and done.